# Setting keyboard shortcuts to additional workspaces

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, workspaces

Coming from the Mac OS, I have a favorite setup where I have 8 Workspaces.

I have no problem setting up the additional Workspaces, and I have 10 up and running right now.

However, I'm used to switching directly to the Workspace I want to go to. In "keyboard shortcuts" I can only find shortcuts to directly address a max of 4 Workspaces. My searches on this topic have only found where people want to *cycle* through Workspaces, not go directly to a known Workspace.

[image]

Is there anyway to directly address additional Workspaces, or am I stuck with directly addressing only 4?

Comment: You can use Ctrl+Page Up and Ctrl+Page Down to switch between workspaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that GNOME Control Center keyboard shortcut do not allow to set shortcuts for workspaces from 5 to 12. But you can specify them using terminal (not user-friendly, but will work):

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-5 "['<Ctrl>5']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-6 "['<Ctrl>6']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-7 "['<Ctrl>7']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-8 "['<Ctrl>8']"
```

---

Small note: on [MATE DE](https://mate-desktop.org/), which looks very similar to macOS (if [Pantheon layout](https://ubuntu-mate.org/gallery/layouts/03_pantheon.png) is used) you can define 8 shortcuts [from GUI in user-friendly way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EI4iY.png) (up to 12).

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for! For others looking to switch directly to additional Workspaces, here is what I use to set and switch directly using the 'Ctrl' key and the Workspace number:    ```gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-5 "['<Ctrl>5']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-6 "['<Ctrl>6']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-7 "['<Ctrl>7']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-8 "['<Ctrl>8']"```

Comment: Great, I edited my answer with yours key-bindings and fixed typos here.

Comment: lol, thankfully I had 2 cups of coffee this morning...it only took me 30 seconds to spot the typo ;)